# Alternate definition of bijection: If $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then $f$ is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ where $g(f(a))=a$ for all $a \in A$, and $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b \in B$.

We know that since $f$ has a left inverse, it is injective. But notice that $g$ also has a left inverse and thus it is also injective.

Does this reasoning show that $f$ is bijective?

Answer (score 1):

You're partway there, but not quite there, yet.

Take any $b\in B.$ Since $g(b)\in A$ and $f(g(b))=b,$ then $f:A\to B$ is....

Alternately, since $f$ has a left inverse, then it is injective, and since $f$ has a right inverse, then it is....

Comment: We know that $f$ is surjective since for all $b \in B$, $b=f(g(b))$. But, I was curious as to whether we can discard the definition of surjective, and only use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are injective.

Comment: Well, knowing only that you have two injective functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ certainly isn't enough in general to show that $f$ is bijective. Cobsider $A=B=\Bbb Z$ and $f(x)=g(x)=2x.$